# Testcafe and cloudflare

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

```
Cloudflare Access expects both values as headers in the request sent to the application. Name them as follows:

CF-Access-Client-Id: &lt;Client ID&gt;
CF-Access-Client-Secret: &lt;Client Secret&gt;
https://developers.cloudflare.com/access/service-auth/service-token/
```

I am new to TestCafe and i have done several tests on our production website and it worked well. However now when i try to access our application on Test environment which is behind cloudfare, i am failing to get through. i read that i should send in headers the above two values. Does anyone know how i can do this in TestCafe? Do let me know if I am missing out any information. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Is the problem reproduced when you perform test actions without TestCafe?

Comment: i have already resolved this via Custom HTTP Request Hook! To answer your question, yes it is reproduced without TestCafe :)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is reproduced without TestCafe.

The user addressed this issue using the [Custom HTTP Request Hook](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/intercepting-http-requests/).